# CSV a PHPMyAdmin campos automáticos

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, csv

Mi campo ID y CREADO los tengo automáticos, o sea que al momento de llenar el formulario estos se generan en la BD sin que el usuario los coloque, pero cuando quiero cargar mi archivo CSV con 200 registros a pesar de que importa correctamente, la fecha me queda en 0000-00-00 y el Id que genera no sigue el orden que lleva la BD si no mas adelante, hay alguna forma de cargar esto automático. Gracias, espero haberme hecho entender.

Comment: Pon la estructura de columnas de la tabla y una muestra del CSV, no tiene que ser todo, con unos 3 o 4 registros basta.

Comment: Ya agregue la información gracias

Answer (score 0):

Uno de los problemas es que no puedes importar directamente la columna `creado` porque no está en el formato de fecha correcto, al no entenderlo lo pone todo en 0. Podrías hacer una conversión a YYYY-MM-DD antes de hacer la importación.

Otra cosa que mencionas es que el campo ID no acepta los valores que le estas enviando, esto se debe a que el puntero del índice de esa tabla es incremental, y ni porque quieras va a aceptar un valor que ya ha pasado. Resolver esto es fácil: dejarle a la base de datos que administre su ID incremental. Sin embargo, si quieres resetearlo y que comience desde 1, debes hacer un truncate:

```
TRUNCATE BaseDeDatos.LaTabla
```

Desde phpmyadmin lo puedes hacer en Operaciones -> Vaciar la tabla (Truncate)

Para facilitarte la vida, puedes usar este importador de CSV a MySQL o MariaDB

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'la_contrasenia', 'BaseDeDatos');

$csv = fopen("archivo.csv", "r"); // <- El archivo CSV
$row_count = 1;

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO la_tabla (id, referencia, precio, cantidad, 
marcaid, creado) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("isiiis", $id, $referencia, $precio, $cantidad, $marcaid, $creado);

while(($data = fgetcsv($csv, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $id = null; //$data[0]; // <- El Id es automatico
    $referencia = $data[1];
    $precio = $data[2];
    $cantidad = $data[3];
    $marcaid = $data[4];
    $creado = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data[5])->format('Y-m-d');
    $stmt->execute();
}
fclose($csv);

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

Obviamente reemplaza algunos datos con los de tu sistema: el usuario, contraseña, BaseDeDatos, la_tabla, archivo.csv.